# NSDate returning NULL

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have this datestring as logged in the console:

2013-8-11 10:00PM

Im running this dateFormatter in order to make it into an NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"]];

    NSDate *openDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:adjustedOpenDateString];

    NSLog(@"DEALWITHTIMESTRINGS = open, now, close %@,%@,%@", openDate,[NSDate date], closeDate);
```

But when I log it, openDate shows up NULL.  So does closeDate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space between `hh:mm` and `a` in your format string is likely causing it to fail.

Instead you'll want to do this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma"];
```

Comment: In the test I just did, the space broke the parsing.

Comment: I tested this as well and removing the space between the AM/PM specifier resulted in a proper `NSDate` object. I thought it might have been because the date format specified two digits for the month and the date string contained only one, but it was the AM/PM specifier after all.

Comment: In the app I just finished, It works fine. But whatever, if it works, it works!

Comment: Today both hh:mma and hh:mm a return null dates.  At least on the device. They seem to work fine on the simulator.